# automatically generate a pdf or word from LoadRunner Analysis 11

Tags: pdf, analysis, loadrunner

In LoadRunner Analysis there are some options in the "Template Dialog Box" for generating PDF, Excel, Word and HTML. How can I run the analysis tool from the command line having the reports generated automatically?

I succeeded so far to generate HTML, but this one is an additional option in the upper part of the dialog.

Comment: I asked HP and got the following answer: You should check the Generate the following automated Rich Reports to be positive, then check the desired file types for the template you are using and user Save and Close button.
By default LoadRunner saves the automated rich reports in Windows Temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

To kick this process off from the command line, assuming you do not automatically load analysis at the conclusion of a test, simply kick off the the analysis engine by issuing the following command from the command prompt

```
c:\<my results path>  START <Name of my LoadRunner test results>.lrr
```

LRR (LoadRunner Results> files are associated with the analysis engine through the Windows registry and this will force analysis to kick off to load the results data.   Your default template will be applied in this case.   You can set up the default template to automatically dump your output in various formats.